# Python PytQT5 - Windows Buttons move to other area

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qmainwindow

I am looking for help, I am developing a web browser using PyQT5 and its included web engine, however, I got one problem which I do not seem to find a way to solve. Basically, I am trying to move windows buttons - Minimize, Change windows Size and Close buttons to the ToolBar area as Google Chrome has. Explanation:

Windows buttons at the right - on the Windows Frame

[image]

Now, I remove the window frame and those 3 buttons disappear(As they should):

No Windows Frame

[image]

Now essentially that is what I want, that there would be no frame, but the windows buttons would move to the Tab/TabBar or ToolBar. Like Google chrome has:

Google Chrome Example

[image]

I disable the Window frame with this code:

```
def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent, Qt.FramelessWindowHint, *args, **kwargs)
```

But now I do not know how to move those three buttons to the Tab bar or Toolbar. I found out that I could use "Flags", specifically these three:

```
Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint
Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint
Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint
```

Now I create my Tab widget using this code:

```
    self.tabs = QTabWidget()
    self.tabs.setDocumentMode(True)
    self.tabs.tabBarDoubleClicked.connect(self.tab_open_doubleclick)
    self.tabs.currentChanged.connect(self.current_tab_changed)
    self.tabs.setTabsClosable(True)
    self.tabs.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.close_current_tab)

    self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)
```

After that, I create the Status bar and navigation bar:

```
    self.status = QStatusBar()
    self.setStatusBar(self.status)

    navigation_bar = QToolBar('Navigation')
    navigation_bar.setIconSize(QSize(24, 24))
    self.addToolBar(navigation_bar)
```

After that I add buttons to the Tool Bar - Stop, Reload, Back and Forward and etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself, well is kinda not the thing I was looking for but it will do.

I disabled the frame with the flags - which then disables the 3 flags I have posted before. Then I created 3 new buttons at the Toolbar and changed their Icons to be windows buttons, the last step was to add back the functionality of those 3 buttons, which I did with 2 functions.

---

**Solved.**